# SIM800L with Raspberry Pi Pico takes too much time to make http request

Tags: pi-pico, gps, gsm

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico with SIM800l and NEO6M to make a GPS tracker. But it takes about 8s (from recording the GPS signal) to make a http request to the the server.

I'm using this library as a base for the drivers https://github.com/pythings/Drivers/blob/e4a45741aad16b026b1a4ea02dc9b486367805b7/SIM800L.py

My complete code: https://github.com/BT-P1C0/BT-Hardware

How can I reduce the request time to make the tracker more real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Use UDP instead of HTTP/TCP. Create a simple message block with the position data, and send it twice, and get the server to send an acknowledgement. If 2 attempts fail, then you are probably in an area with poor wireless coverage, so there is no point in more retries; just store the failed data, and add it to the next transfer.

The reason TCP can be slow is that it involves a lot of to-and-fro traffic to set up & tear down the connection (11 datagrams for a short message: syn, syn-ack, ack, data, ack, data, ack, fin, ack, fin, ack) with each of these incurring a round-trip delay that may be over 1 second, plus one or more retries if there are errors. Compare that with UDP (2 datagrams for a short message: data, ack).

TCP is incredibly inefficient for short messages over potentially-unreliable wireless links.